# APPCRASH in Windows Event Viewer -- Application Didn't Crash?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, mingw, dump

I noticed in the Windows Event Viewer that my application (C / C++) developed with MinGW crashes all the time, only it doesn't. The application doesn't crash, it runs just fine. I'm concerned the event viewer errors may belie a deeper issue.

I can even look at a heap dump from the offending process and see that the process fails for an access write violation, again though, it didn't actually crash.

Is anyone else familiar with this? I can't recreate it on my development PC, only a target.

**Update 7/7/2021**

I'm noticing a lot of the crash reports have older dumps and it's just the Report.wer file that is updated (almost continuously). Does anyone know why the OS is constantly reporting seemingly old crashes?

[image]

Comment: Is your program or any library you are using catching Structured Exceptions (note not C++ exceptions) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/structured-exception-handling-c-cpp?view=msvc-160  also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/structured-exception-handling

Comment: I link to libgcc_seh-1.dll as part of the MinGW dependency packages. I do not use, nor am I aware of any component libraries using the `_try` ... syntax. 

I do also include and link to Windows.h for serial port access. 

For discussion's sake, let's say I did use an SEH, how would that manifest as this behavior?

Comment: How do you see in a heap dump that the process fails with an access write violation?

Comment: Windows event viewer includes a few dump files which can be opened with visual studio.

Comment: Any luck with this Foo? I too have an application (C#) which generates lots of APPCRASH events, despite the application not crashing.

Comment: Sadly no. I eventually migrated this application to linux.